# Powerhsell : Multiple Value in properties Variable

Tags: powershell, properties

From a primal form with checkbox I get a csv file with some properties.
I want to used these properties with cmdlet get-Adusers. The script is working if I only have only one value in the csv but not with some.

My CSV file is format like this :

```
"PropertiesSelected";"FilterSelected"
"SN,EmailAddress,CN,SamAccountName"; "DC=myDomain,DC=COM"
```

For the moment I don't try to used `"filterSelected"`
I think the problem is that `powershell` understand `"SN,EmailAddress,CN,SamAccountName"` as a single value

The command I used is like that : 
`Import-Csv c:\TempPowerShell\CheckBoxResults.csv -delimiter ";" |`

```
ForEach-Object {

$FilterSelected=$_.FilterSelected

$PropertiesSelected=$_.PropertiesSelected

Get-ADUser -Properties "$PropertiesSelected" -Filter * -SearchScope Subtree -SearchBase "DC=MyDomain,DC=COM" -Server MyServer:3268
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help, I'm going to be crazy :)

Regards
Julien

Comment: what output is generated if you write-host $PropertiesSelected? If you want "SN,EmailAddress,CN,SamAccountName" not to be a single value you have to change the generating script or split the string.

Comment: If the column header has spaces, use `$_."Header Name"` and make sure your properties are exactly correct. Also, your CSV has both `;` and `,` as delimiters?

Comment: i think he is trying to use the `,` as seperators for the properties parameter

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your anwser, to precise a bit on my CSV.

Comment: on my form, I have all the attribut can be extract from get-Aduser, it's depend of what checkbox is check. If I manually type Get-AdUser -properties SN,CN,GivenName,..... It's working, so my Idea is to put a variable with all attributes selected "write" as I type it Manually :)

Comment: See my answer below, I think my example with invoke expression should solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use a String with multiple properties as parameter input.

You can get around this by constructing your command as string and then executing it with invoke-expression:

```
$command="get-aduser -properties $PropertiesSelected -Filter * -SearchScope Subtree -SearchBase "DC=MyDomain,DC=COM" -Server MyServer:3268"
Invoke-expression $command
```

Regards Paul

Comment: It's working perfectly with the Invoke-Expression method ! Thanks a Lot! this community rocks !

Answer (score 0):

```
ForEach-Object {

$FilterSelected=$_.FilterSelected

$PropertiesSelected=$_.PropertiesSelected

Get-ADUser -Properties $PropertiesSelected.split(",") -Filter * -SearchScope Subtree -SearchBase "DC=MyDomain,DC=COM" -Server MyServer:3268
}
```

Comment: this is the answer
**$PropertiesSelected.split(",")**