# Custom expression in invoke-expression PowerShell

Tags: powershell, expression

I used Invoke-expression command in PowerShell with this code :

```
$command="Get-ADUser -Properties $PropertiesSelected -filter $FilterSelected -SearchScope Subtree -SearchBase '$DomainSelected' -Server MyServer:3268|Select $PropertiesSelected,$DomainSelected"
Invoke-expression $command
```

1st thing :

in `$PropertiesSelected`, I have the attribute LastLogonTimeStamp, as you know this value is not easy to read without a custom expression.
Usually I used this to convert :

```
@{Name="LastLogonDate"; Expression={[system.DateTime]::FromFileTime($($_.lastLogonTimestamp))}}
```

But if I try to add this at the end of "select" part in my script it's not working :

```
UserExctractWithSelectedPropertiesandDomain.ps1 
+ $command="Get-ADUser -Properties $PropertiesSelected -filter $FilterSelected -Se...

Unexpected token 'LastLogonDate"; Expression={[system.DateTime]::FromFileTime($($_.lastLogonTimestamp))}}"' in expression or statement.
```

I think it's a syntax issue but I don't know how I can solved this.

My second point is about `$DomainSelected` variable.

My complete script is like that :

```
Import-Csv c:\TempPowerShell\CheckBoxResults.csv -delimiter ";"|
ForEach-Object {

$PropertiesSelected=$_.PropertiesSelected
$FilterSelected=$_.FilterSelected

Import-Csv c:\TempPowerShell\CheckBoxResultsDomain.csv -Delimiter ";" |
ForEach-Object{
$DomainSelected=$_.DomainSelected


Write-Host "PropertiesSelected=$PropertiesSelected / FilterSelected=$FilterSelected / DomainSelected=$DomainSelected"
    $command="Get-ADUser -Properties $PropertiesSelected -filter $FilterSelected -SearchScope Subtree -SearchBase '$DomainSelected' -Server D0004bel.bel.com:3268|Select $PropertiesSelected,$DomainSelected,@{Name="LastLogonDate"; Expression={[system.DateTime]::FromFileTime($($_.lastLogonTimestamp))}}"
    Invoke-expression $command 

    } 
        }
```

checkboxresults.csv file content this type of data :

```
PropertiesSelected;FilterSelected
GivenName,sn,TargetAddress,LastLogonTimeStamp ; *
```

CheckBoxResultsDomain.csv file content is like this :

```
DomainSelected
"DC=World,DC=MyDomain,DC=COM"
"DC=pt,DC=MyDomain,DC=COM"
"DC=jp,DC=MyDomain,DC=COM"
```

When I execute my script I want to have the domain selected for each line but I have it only on the first line.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Invoke-Expression isn't necessary here - try getting rid of it.  In general, Invoke-Expression isn't that useful and usually just makes it harder to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for reply, in fact the $ propertiesSelected is generate by a checkbox and if I not used invok expression it's not working because my checkboxes export a value like that :

Comment: PropertiesSelected;FilterSelected
GivenName,sn,TargetAddress,LastLogonTimeStamp ; *

Comment: I still think Invoke-Expression is making your task more difficult than necessary - e.g. you aren't escaping things you need to.  See my blog post here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: Thanks Jason, so do you know how I can put some "text" as properties in my variable $propertiesSelected, because this variable is composed by text : parameter1,parameter2,... And I think when I used get-AdUser -Properties $propertiesSelected, $propertiesSelected is not interpreted as multi-properties but as only one property so it's not working. And if it just do a copy/paste of the content of $propertiesselected in the command it's working :/

Comment: $propertiesSelected doesn't need to be text, you can have an array.  After Import-CSV, assuming $_.propertiesSelected is a comma delimited list, try:  $propertiesSelected = $_.propertiesSelected -split ','; $propertiesSelected += $domainSelected,@{Name='LastLogonData'; Expression={...}}

Comment: I already try this, but the problem is with split, the properties are in some lines and not in one, so I have to make a foreach loop and it's not good, I need to used all properties in the same time just like if text.

Comment: I do that with your advice :

Comment: $propertiesSelected = $_.propertiesSelected -split ','; and $lastLogonTime=@{Name='LastLogonDate'; Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($($_.lastlogontimestamp))}} and now it's working for the command but not for the select part :) : Get-ADUser -Properties $PropertiesSelected -filter $FilterSelected -SearchScope Subtree -SearchBase $DomainSelected -Server myserver.com:3268 |Select "$propertiesSelected,$lastLogonTime"

Comment: You turned the array into a string with the quotes.  Try ... | Select (@($propertiesSelected) + $lastLogonTime)

Comment: Thanks Jason, it's working ! you rocks !! thanks a lot !

Comment: And Do you know if it's possible to remove LastLogonTimeStamp column from the array ? I create a variable $SelectedObjectForSelect with the exactly same properties of $SelectedObject, I want to keep the readable $lastLogontime and remove unreadable lastlogontimeStamp properties. Thanks a lot. Regards

Comment: Sure, try something like $properties -ne 'LastLogonTimeStamp'

Comment: I'm probably not good, I try to add another properties Proxyaddresses in the select exclusion but it's not working :/ I don't understand why : (@(($propertiesSelectedForSelect -ne 'LastLogonTimeStamp')) + $ProxyAddressesTrad + $lastLogonTime) is working perfectly but if I try (@(($propertiesSelectedForSelect -ne (('LastLogonTimeStamp') -and ('Proxyaddresses')) + $ProxyAddressesTrad + $lastLogonTime) there is no error but it's like there is no exclusion... Someone know a good tuto about syntax in powershell ? thanks for help

Comment: solved just have to  -ne 'ProxyAddresses' :) thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error in your select statement is easily fixed by replacing `"` with `'` in your calculated property:

```
@{Name='LastLogonDate'; Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}}
```

I'm not sure what you mean by the second question though, care to elaborate?

Comment: hi, thanks for answer. It's not working, no more syntax error but the following message :

Comment: for info it's related to this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019742/powerhsell-multiple-value-in-properties-variable/21020583?noredirect=1#21020583